# Why does assigning an observer to a subject in the subscribe break sometimes?

Tags: rxjs

Imagine the following simple case:

- you get some data from a source, resulting in an observable, lets call it obs$
- you need to transform it (frex a simple synchronous sort) and hand the result some kind of subject, lets call it subject$$

You now have several ways to implement it. The simplest might look like:

```
obs$
    .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.#destroy$$)
    )
    .subscribe(
        result => { 
            this.subject$$.next(result.dSomething()) 
    });
```

Works like a charm. A bit later you write some more similar functions, and thus would like to separate the transformation from the assignment. Basically you move the doSomething from the subscribe to a map in the pipe. This could look like:

```
obs$
    .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.#destroy$$),
        map(result => result.dSomething())
    )
    .subscribe(res => { this.subject$$.next(res) });
```

Works fine as well. Though the assignment now looks a bit clunky, surely there is a better way to do this? You might be tempted to go for something like:

```
obs$
    .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.#destroy$$),
        map(result => result.dSomething())
    )
    .subscribe(this.subject$$.next);
```

But quickly find that this fails, as you've got no access to your outer scopes this. The suggested solution looks like this:

```
obs$
    .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.#destroy$$),
        map(result => result.dSomething())
    )
    .subscribe(this.subject$$);
```

Which works just fine in many cases.

Imagine my surprise, when all of a sudden I stumbled into a waterfall of errors:

EmptyError: no elements in sequence

showing up in four completely unrelated places, bubbling up through the code, without an obvious place to even try catch it.

Now following the white rabbit, I searched for far to long until I finally managed to discover the place of origin. Still it doesn't make any sense to me.

Why is the observer "disconnecting" for a moment when there is no activity that could result in a complete? Funnily enough, the subject is catching back up shortly afterwards, so this is not completely breaking the assignment.

Of course, I can always use the slightly more verbose assignment, but understanding why this fails only in some cases would really help avoid those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very hard to suggest anything because I don't know what part of your code and what RxJS chain gives you the `EmptyError`.

However, I'm suspicious that the problem comes from `.subscribe(this.subject$$)` because this is not the same as `.subscribe(res => this.subject$$.next(res));`

All Subjects behave like Observables and observers at the same time. Observers implement [this interface](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/interface/Observer) that handles all three notification types. If you use `.subscribe(this.subject$$)` you're passing also `error` and `complete` notifications from the source Observable to `subject$$` and this is very like your problem. When `obs$` completes, the `complete` notification is passed to `subject$$` that completes as well and since it's a Subject it will never ever emit any `next` again and to all its new observers it'll just pass `complete` notification and that's it. So this might explain why you're seeing `EmptyError` somewhere else in you chains that use `subject$$`.

With `.subscribe(res => this.subject$$.next(res));` you're only passing `next` notifications and `complete` or `error` notifications are ignored.

Comment: *nod* I know it's hard to track and that was my problem here as well. The code is, what's called legacy? Let's say it has grown over some time and was written by people with differing skill levels and there surely was a priority on speed of implementation over maintainability.

Still I think you are on the right track here, and have given me a good hint on where to start untangling this mess. I was aware that there is a difference between subscribe(this.subject$$.next) which doesn't work, and subscribe(this.subject$$), but I hadn't fully grasped the implications of handing the observer. Thx